# Flutter Bloc package, yield state when native code invoke a method from dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

In my bloc I have 2 streams. One is the `mapEventToState` where I can yield states, and I created a second one which is called from a function which is called by native code.

The call:

```
checkStatus(_internalState).listen((data){});
```

The Stream:

```
Stream<VpnConnectionState> checkStatus(_internalState) async * {
switch (_internalState) {
  case state.down:
    yield down();
    break;
  case state.up:
    yield up();
    break;
}
_previousState = _internalState;
}
```

The problem is when I `yield` something in the `checkSatus` stream, is not arriving in my BlocBuilder. If is called from the stream `mapEventToState` is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are completely different streams. Your `BlocBuilder` is listening to your `mapEventToState` stream not for your `checkStatus`. `Dispatch`(or `add` in the latest version) event from your checkStatus stream to your block and then yield new state in `mapEventToState` when responding to those events.

Or even get rid of your checkStatus stream for simplicity like here:

```
void checkStatus(_internalState) {
switch (_internalState) {
  case state.down:
     dispatch(DownEvent());
    break;
  case state.up:
    dispatch(UpEvent());
    break;
}
_previousState = _internalState;
}

void mapEventToSteam(Event event) {
    if(event is DownEvent) {
     yield DownState()
   }
    if(event is UpEvent) {
     yield UpState()
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that is a dispatch() function which can be called without context inside bloc.

Comment: I was no aware about using `add()` (or `dispatch`). It's brilliant and so.. simple! You saved my day.